# Calculate average time from DateTime2 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns with employee in time and out time, but those are in DateTime2.

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|            Date             |           InTime            |           OutTime           |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-01-01 09:45:00.0000000 | 2019-01-01 11:14:00.0000000 | <
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-01-04 18:32:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | <
| 2019-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2019-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 | 2019-01-07 14:17:00.0000000 | 2019-01-07 15:03:00.0000000 | <
| 2019-01-08 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

So as you can see, some rows contain time but some don't. What I want to is remove the date portion and get the avarage of time for both columns.

So far I have been using this query.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(5), 
            Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(InTime as time)) AS bigint)), '00:00:00' ) as Time ),108) AS 'AVG_IN_TIME',
        CONVERT(varchar(5), 
            Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(OutTime as time)) AS bigint)), '00:00:00' ) as Time ),108) AS 'AVG_OUT_TIME'
FROM [HCMSync].[dbo].[Attendances]
Where [Email address] = 'email@domain.com' and [Date] between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-08'
```

But this gives me,

```
+-------------+--------------+
| AVG_IN_TIME | AVG_OUT_TIME |
+-------------+--------------+
| 05:19       | 03:17        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

which I don't think is accurate, because if there is only one record with time, like this,

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|           InTime            |           OutTime           |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2019-01-07 09:42:00.0000000 | 2019-01-07 11:23:00.0000000 | < This record.
| 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1901-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

..it returns the following result. It should have provided me with 09:42 and 11:23. And I even calculated the average manually and it returned different results.

```
+-------------+--------------+
| AVG_IN_TIME | AVG_OUT_TIME |
+-------------+--------------+
| 01:12       | 01:25        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I tried many online solutions but I cannot use any of those because most of them uses `-` operator and resulted in,

> Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.

And some answers tried to convert the datetime field into float which resulted in,

> Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to float is not allowed.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: try removing zeros from you result

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: FYI, `DATEDIFF` doesn't return a `bigint`, it returns an `int`, and casting it to a `bigint` won't achieve anything here. If you want a `bigint` use [`DATEDIFF_BIG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and drop the `CAST`.

Comment: @VishalGupta I cannot remove the 0's because data is inserted in that format by a 3rd party, and cannot change `DateTime2` to `DateTime`

Comment: @dnoeth SQL Server 14.03035

Comment: @Larnu Noted, I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those midnight rows cause that problem, they lower the average.

You must remove them from the average calulation using NULLIF.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(5), 
            Cast(DateAdd(s, AVG(NULLIF(DateDiff( s, '00:00:00', cast(InTime as time)), 0)), '00:00:00' ) as Time ),108) AS 'AVG_IN_TIME',
        CONVERT(varchar(5), 
            Cast(DateAdd(s, AVG(NULLIF(DateDiff( s, '00:00:00', cast(OutTime as time)),0)), '00:00:00' ) as Time ),108) AS 'AVG_OUT_TIME'
```

I removed the bigint cast and switched to seconds, too, as you only want minutes in your result.

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth This is marvelous. I never thought those midnight columns has any value at all. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to achieve this

```
    SELECT (SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, InTime) * 60) + SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, InTime))) / (SELECT COUNT(InTime) FROM #Temp WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, InTime) <> 0) / 60 AS [InTime avg hours]
        , (SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, InTime) * 60) + SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, InTime))) / (SELECT COUNT(InTime) FROM #Temp WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, InTime) <> 0) % 60 AS [InTime avg minutes]
        , (SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, OutTime) * 60) + SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, OutTime))) / (SELECT COUNT(OutTime) FROM #Temp WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, OutTime) <> 0) / 60 AS [OutTime avg hours]
        , (SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, OutTime) * 60) + SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, OutTime))) / (SELECT COUNT(OutTime) FROM #Temp WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, OutTime) <> 0) % 60 AS [OutTime avg minutes]
    FROM #Temp
```